# When can I delete files from GCS when downloading to GEE?

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-python-api

I am downloading data from GCS to GEE using the following code:

```py
# define the GEE parameters for exportation
gcs_shp = next(f for f in shp_files if f.suffix == ".shp")
gcs_shp = f"gs://{bucket}/{gcs_shp.name}"
sources = [{"maxVertices": 1000000, "uris": gcs_shp, "crs": crs}]
params = {"name": assetId.as_posix(), "sources": sources}

# download the shapefile to GEE
try:
    task_id = ee.data.startTableIngestion(ee.data.newTaskId()[0], params)["id"]
    wait_for_task(task_id, timeout=timeout)
except Exception as e:
    assetId = ""
    print(e)
finally:
    gcs.bucket.delete_blobs([f.name for f in shp_files])
```

When can I flush the files from GCS ? My intuition is telling me that once the task as started I'm good to go and I can flush the data but I'm not 100% sure. Can someone confirm that I should not wait for completion nor failure of the task?

Comment: Why would your intuition think you could trash data before you know it has been used?

Comment: because I accidentally reached the wait timeout on my last attempt (so I flushed the GCS before the end of the GEE task) and the process ended just fine on server's side.  So I guess that GEE is copying the data in memory and the rest is server-side ingestion.